# How to select an input element by value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've seen it's jquery equivalent:

```
$('input[value="something"]');
```

But how do you select it using pure javascript (no jQuery).

Thanks for all the responses so far but I'm sure if it is working correctly, I need to change the value of the input into something else. I though I could do this by

```
<enter snippet to select element here>.value = "someOtherValue";
```

But it appears to be not that easy. Any ideas.

Comment: Use getElementsByTagName (defined in DOM) to get a list of all input tags, and then filter them in Javascript code (looking at their value attribute). After you have done this a few times, rethink why you want to avoid jQuery.

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001917/queryselectorall-with-multiple-conditions/55288394#55288394 Another way to resolve this case.

Comment: Luckily in the past 10 years JavaScript has advanced quite a bit! https://youmightnotneedjquery.com

Answer (score 51, accepted):

with ie6-ie7-ie8

```
function getInputsByValue(value)
{
    var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var results = [];
    for(var x=0;x<allInputs.length;x++)
        if(allInputs[x].value == value)
            results.push(allInputs[x]);
    return results;
}
```

with modern browsers ie9+ (? not sure for ie9 actually) :

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[value=something]");
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` on modern browsers (https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), e.g.

```
var byValue = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="something"]');
```

For older browsers you'll have to iterate over the `input`s and check the value, e.g.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    i,
    len,
    byVal = [],
    value = "something";

for (i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].value === value) {
        byVal.push(inputs[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this works:

```
function getCheckboxByValue(v) {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].value == v) {
                        return inputs[i];
                }
        }
        return false;
}
(function testCheckbox() {
        getCheckboxByValue("1").checked = true;
})();
```

Using jQuery would be much better, though.

Comment: only returns the first one, though.

Comment: I've been working on a similar project. This answer solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
var elems = [].filter.call( document.getElementsByTagName("input"), function( input ) {
    return input.value === "something";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ts2Rr/3/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work...

```
for(i in document.getElementsByTagName('input')) {
   if(i.value == 'desiredValue') {
      return i;
   }
}
```

Edit: This will return an array of all matches

```
var matches = [];
for(i in document.getElementsByTagName('input')) {
   if(i.value == 'desiredValue') {
      matches.push(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: true, a quick amendment will fix that

Answer (score 0):

This might be **overboard in most cases**, but an alternative method would be to use [`document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) with an XPath expression to select the input field by value:

```
let result = document.evaluate(
  '//input[@value="something"]',
  document,
  null,
  XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,
  null
).iterateNext();

result.value = 'someOtherValue';
```

> **Note:** This method is not supported by Internet Explorer.

Otherwise, use one of the other mentioned methods for better browser compatibility and speed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all elements by ID you can use

```
function getElementsById(elementID){
    var elementCollection = new Array();
    var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++){
        if(allElements[i].id == elementID){
            elementCollection.push(allElements[i]);
        }
    }
    return elementCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you need the name or ID this will work:

`${RegRowFullName}=  Get Element Attribute  xpath=//input[@value="Dragon"]  name`