# Bypassing a blocked frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame with postMessage()

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage, cross-origin-read-blocking

I've heard that you can bypass a "blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame" with postMessage() and I've been trying to use it, but it's not working properly. What am I doing wrong?

```
<iframe src="www.example.com" id = "theID"></iframe>

document.getElementById('theID').contentWindow.postMessage({
document.querySelector("input[value='true']").click();
});
```

Comment: Can you edit both webpages?

Comment: @zer00ne No I cannot. And I don't want to disable the same-origin policy in my browser because I heard it's a security breach.

Comment: Don't worry about it because you can't do it. You need to setup both pages to communicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your server as a proxy. Assuming that you intend to load page XYZ inside the iframe, you can create an XYZ.php page which sends a request to XYZ and displays the response in the page. You will need to resolve the problems which might arise from relative URLs. Also, make sure that whatever you do is goodwilling and legal.

The flow will look like this:

- request for parent.php is sent to the server
- the server responds with parent.php to the browser
- inside the structure of parent.php you have an iframe pointing to child.php, which is your page as well
- child.php on its turn sends a request to the actual source and sends back the respond it receives to the browser
- an onload event for the iframe will trigger the logic for parent.php which you intended to execute

Comment: I don't actually own the server though.

Comment: @frosty you do not need to own the server. If you are able to load the page into a browser as a user, then your server should be able to get the page source via a request and display it in your browser.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me, or perhaps I'm misunderstanding you. But to be clear, I do not own either of the websites, and I did not create either of the websites. I cannot edit any part of the PHP codes. I'm merely a user of the websites. Perhaps if you include some example codes above, I might be able to understand a little better? Nothing too complicated. Just a little example code to get me started. Thanks.

Comment: @frosty do you try to hack the sites?

Comment: What? No. I'm just trying to auto select the radio buttons of a form that is in an iframe from another website.